# Backslash Vs Forwardslash in Javascript json

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my ASP.NET project, I had to change the path where **project.json** can be found. I had to use forward slash in the json file to work when in other places like html or javascript where I can use backward slash.

Does not work:

```
project = require("..\..\project.json");
```

Works:

```
project = require("../../project.json");
```

Why should I use forward slash and not backward slash?

Comment: Good for you. So what is the question?

Comment: Is the question about javascript or in ASP.net?

Comment: The question is about why I can't use backslash in the path which is used in a json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because \ is an escape character. `..\..\project.json` is the string `....project.json`

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the `\` character starts an escape sequence.

Your first string doesn't have a backslash character in it at all, it has an escaped `.` and an escaped `p` instead.

If you wanted to backslash character, you would have to escape it: `\\`.

You appear to be trying to write a file path. Practically every system will support a forwards slash as a directory separator. (Backslashes for directory separators are a Microsoft peculiarity). So always use `/` for directory separators in code.